# Login to apache server using a web page

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I have this code right here:

```html
<html>
    <body style="color:white;background-color:#222222">
        <center>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="username"> Username</input>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="password"> Password</input>
            <br><br>
            <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
            <p id="url"/>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function test(){
                    var userInput = document.getElementById("username").value;
                    var userPass = document.getElementById("password").value;
                    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = encodeURI('http://'+userInput+':'+userPass+'@'+window.location.hostname+':81/Home/');
                }
            </script>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

It outputs an url that *works*. It logs me into my password-protected folders when I specify the right password.
Only problem, I want the "Submit" button to automaticly redirect me to the specified page instead of showing me the url.

I tried everything.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting location.href?

Comment: like, replace `document.getElementById("url").innerHTML` to `location.href`?

Comment: Im back, it worked. I feel dumb now. Thanks. Alot.

Comment: I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:

```
function test(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var userPass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    location.href = encodeURI('http://'+userInput+':'+userPass+'@'+window.location.hostname+':81/Home/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = etc
```

make it

```
window.location.href = etc
```